# Starting/stopping H2 with ant

Tags: ant, automated-tests, h2

I installed H2 on a Windows PC.
I would start H2 from ant so that it can be automatically started/stopped during a test suite execution.
How can I do this with ant?
Have I to call .bat in ./service directory or what?
I can't find any H2-ant-tasks library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no particular task, probably the best way is to make use of the `<exec>` task and call the appropriate .bat files.